# Soundcloud API in local Ruby app?

Tags: ruby, soundcloud

I am trying to access the Soundcloud API in a local .rb file on my computer.

This is the code I would use in a Ruby on Rails app:

```
require 'soundcloud'

# create a client object with your app credentials
client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => 'MY_CLIENT_ID')

# find all sounds of buskers licensed under 'creative commons share alike'
tracks = client.get('/tracks', :q => 'buskers', :licence => 'cc-by-sa')
```

How can i rewrite this to work in a local .rb file on my computer (not in a ruby on rails app)?

Comment: It's just Ruby code, so why wouldn't it work in just a regular Ruby program? Are you wondering how to run Ruby locally?

Comment: I can run it in the terminal, but then I get this error: `/Users/ole/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require': cannot load such file -- soundcloud (LoadError)` `from /Users/ole/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'`

Comment: Check the rvm and gemset version you are using when you are on terminal. And the same versions you are using while running your script. In the directory of file, you can run `gem list | grep sound` to check if it is actually there in that gemset or not.

Comment: When I run `gem list | grep sound` I get nothing, it isn't in the gem list. Any idea on how to solve this? Does it need to be in the gem list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a Gemfile in the same directory you're making the .rb file that would utilize the Soundcloud API wrapper gem, then specify the gem in there. Using Bundler it should detect the gem on your machine and utilize it locally.